# PyQt5 Curved QSlider

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter

I've been playing around with customising PyQt widgets using paint events. I've been trying to customise the QSlider widget and have had some success, mostly with CSS styling. However, I'm having difficulty making it curved with a QPainterPath as it always seems flat. Is this something that is beyond the capability of this widget (which would surprise me)? The below is my most recent attempt of many with no success. I tried path points instead of cubicTo() with the same. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class slider(QtWidgets.QSlider):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(slider, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setMinimum(10)
        self.setMaximum(30)
        self.setValue(20)
        self.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        self.setTickInterval(5)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.drawCurve(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawCurve(self, qp):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(30, 30)
        path.cubicTo(30, 30, 200, 350, 200, 30)
        qp.drawPath(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the sensation of depth it is only to choose the correct colors, for this QPainterPathStroker is also used. On the other hand I added the functionality that the QPainterPath is scaled:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class PathSlider(QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider):
    def __init__(self, path=QtGui.QPainterPath(), *args, **kwargs):
        super(PathSlider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._path = path
        self.stroke_path = self._path
        self.scale_path = self._path

    def setPath(self, path):
        path.translate(-path.boundingRect().topLeft())
        self._path = path
        self.update()

    def path(self):
        return self._path

    path = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QPainterPath, fget=path, fset=setPath)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        border = 10
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        sx, sy = (self.rect().width() -2*border)/self.path.boundingRect().width(), \
                 (self.rect().height() -2*border)/self.path.boundingRect().height()
        tr = QtGui.QTransform()
        tr.translate(border, border)
        tr.scale(sx, sy)
        self.scale_path = tr.map(self.path)
        stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroker.setCapStyle(QtCore.Qt.RoundCap)
        stroker.setWidth(4)
        stroke_path = stroker.createStroke(self.scale_path).simplified()
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Shadow), 1))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Midlight)))
        painter.drawPath(stroke_path)
        stroker.setWidth(20)
        self.stroke_path = stroker.createStroke(self.scale_path).simplified()
        percentage = (self.value() - self.minimum())/(self.maximum() - self.minimum())
        highlight_path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        highlight_path.moveTo(self.scale_path.pointAtPercent(0))
        n_p = int((self.maximum() + 1 - self.minimum())/self.singleStep())
        for i in range(n_p+1):
            d = i*percentage/n_p
            p = self.scale_path.pointAtPercent(d)
            highlight_path.lineTo(p)
        stroker.setWidth(3)
        new_phighlight_path = stroker.createStroke(highlight_path).simplified()

        activeHighlight = self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight)
        painter.setPen(activeHighlight)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(activeHighlight)))
        painter.drawPath(new_phighlight_path)

        opt  = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionSlider()
        r = self.style().subControlRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_Slider, opt, QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_SliderHandle, self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(r.width() + 2*2, r.height() + 2*2)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        r = pixmap.rect().adjusted(2, 2, -2, -2)
        pixmap_painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        pixmap_painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        pixmap_painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Shadow), 2))
        pixmap_painter.setBrush(self.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Base))
        pixmap_painter.drawRoundedRect(r, 4, 4)
        pixmap_painter.end()
        r.moveCenter(p.toPoint())
        painter.drawPixmap(r, pixmap)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(15, 15)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(336, 336)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.update_pos(event.pos())
        super(PathSlider, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.update_pos(event.pos())
        super(PathSlider, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def update_pos(self, point):
        if self.stroke_path.contains(point):
            n_p = int((self.maximum() + 1 - self.minimum())/self.singleStep())
            ls = []
            for i in range(n_p):
                p = self.scale_path.pointAtPercent(i*1.0/n_p)
                ls.append(QtCore.QLineF(point, p).length())
            j = ls.index(min(ls))
            val = int(j*(self.maximum() + 1 - self.minimum())/n_p)
            self.setValue(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    s1 = PathSlider(minimum=0, maximum=100)
    s2 = PathSlider(minimum=0, maximum=100)
    s = QtWidgets.QSlider(minimum=0, maximum=100)
    s.valueChanged.connect(s1.setValue)
    s.valueChanged.connect(s2.setValue)
    s1.valueChanged.connect(s.setValue)
    s2.valueChanged.connect(s.setValue)

    c1 = QtCore.QPointF(5, -15) 
    c2 = QtCore.QPointF(220, -15) 
    path = QtGui.QPainterPath(QtCore.QPointF(5, 100)) 
    path.cubicTo(c1, c2, QtCore.QPointF(235, 100))
    s1.setPath(path)

    c1 = QtCore.QPointF(5, 15) 
    c2 = QtCore.QPointF(220, 15) 
    path = QtGui.QPainterPath(QtCore.QPointF(5, -100)) 
    path.cubicTo(c1, c2, QtCore.QPointF(235, -100))
    s2.setPath(path)

    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(s1)
    lay.addWidget(s2)
    lay.addWidget(s)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Eyllanesc. I've spent the last few days reading up on much of these classes and methods. I'm struggling slightly with inversed curves. If I use these co-ords:
`c1 = QtCore.QPointF(5, -15)
c2 = QtCore.QPointF(220, -15)
self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath(QtCore.QPointF(5, 100))
self._path.cubicTo(c1, c2, QtCore.QPointF(235, 100))`
I get a lovely semi-circle. If I try to inverse it, it's always slanted, e.g:
`c1 = QtCore.QPointF(5, 15)
c2 = QtCore.QPointF(220, 15)
self._path = QtGui.QPainterPath(QtCore.QPointF(5, -100))
self._path.cubicTo(c1, c2, QtCore.QPointF(235, -100))`

Comment: @xnemesis I had considered in my tests that the QPainterPath belongs to the quadrant where x and y are positive, so that was my mistake, excuse me. Now I solve it. On the other hand do not forget to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: Always eyllanesc, you’re my python guru at the moment ;) thanks!